# API URL not working in volley and working in browser url hit

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, android-volley

URL example = http://webapi.example.com/api/order?data={...list[{...},{...}]}

```
 GsonRequest request = new GsonRequest<OrderResponse>("URL example", null,
            OrderResponse.class, null, new Response.Listener<OrderResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(OrderResponse response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                //sendNotification();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(DeliveryManagementActivity.this, "Error in Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

For the above code I am getting 400 error.

```
GsonRequest request = new GsonRequest<OrderResponse>(UrlConstants.SEND_ORDERS_URL, getParams(),
            OrderResponse.class, header, new Response.Listener<OrderResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(OrderResponse response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                sendNotification();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(DeliveryManagementActivity.this, "Error in Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            hideLoader();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(DeliveryManagementActivity.this, "Error " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hideLoader();
        }
    });

public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return headers;
}

private Map<String, String> getParams() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("orderData", requestData.getOrderRequest(requestData));

    return params;
}
```

For the above I am getting always false wrong response from server. I copied the  request from 1st request method and used browser url to hit the API. It worked well.

**Edited:**

After changing to second way, the request is going like below.

**url** = www.url.com/addOrder.php?

**params** = {"orderData":"{\"deliveryTime\":\"2017-12-10 01:13:00\",\"orderDetail\":[{\"courseId\":\"1\",\"foodQuantity\":\"2\",\"offer_id\":\"-1\",\"type\":\"1\"}],\"userID\":\"7\",\"userLocation\":\"17\"}"}

The **orderData** also parsing inside the json and missing **=**. Is that is the issue. The url at the top of question is actual and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After encoding the url the issue is fixed.

```
 try {
        param = URLEncoder.encode("json", "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

String url = baseUrl + params;

 GsonRequest request = new GsonRequest<OrderResponse>(url, null,
        OrderResponse.class, null, new Response.Listener<OrderResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(OrderResponse response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            //sendNotification();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(DeliveryManagementActivity.this, "Error in Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the query param name **orderData**? The query param used in the url is *data*. 
Else code looks ok.

Comment: It would be helpful to debug the issue, if you could post the error message. One more question is does both the code snippet throw 400?